# Can I safely move the LaTeX doc folder in Linux from the distribution folder to the local texmf/ folder?

Tags: installing, linux, documentation, texmf

Latex's documentation is quite big and I am now running out of space on `/` .

I have the main Latex installation under `/` , where I have a folder `../texmf-dist/doc/` which is quite big. I have space left in my home folder, so my question is: 
Can I safely move all of `doc/` to my local `~/texmf` folder?

I especially want to keep the `texdoc XYZ`functionality, which is quite useful.